# Laravel 4: Eloquent relations with cross-model options

Tags: templates, laravel, eloquent

I'm trying to make a simple template system.

I have these models: `Page`, `Template` and `Templatevariable`.

So a `Page` has a `Template`, and that `Template` has `Templatevariables`. However, there are only a few different `Templates`, but many `Templatevariables` for the different `Pages`.

The `templatevariables` table has both a `template_id` and a `page_id`, so I know which `Page` they belong to.

My problem is, I don't know how to do this with Eloquent. In the `Template` model, if I do this:

```
public function variables() {
    return $this->hasMany('Templatevariable');
}
```

It will return *all* the `Templatevariables` of that that `Template`, not specific to the `Page`. I obviously don't want that. I want to be able to do something like this (in my controller):

```
public function show($id) {
    $page = Page::find($id)
    $template = $page->template;
    foreach($template->variables as $variable)
        $data[$variable->name] = $variable->value;

    $data['page'] = $page;

    return View::make($template->view, $data);
}
```

I imagine this is very possible to make automagic in the model, but I can't figure out how.

Thanks!

Sorry if I'm doing this incorrectly, first time posting here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply retrieve only the variables with the desired `page_id` by using `where()`. Either in the relationship:

```
public function variables(){
    return $this->hasMany('Templatevariable')->where('page_id', $this->page->id);
}
```

(If the Template table contains the `page_id` you can also use `->where('page_id', $this->page_id)` directly)

Or when querying:

```
$template = $page->template;
$variables = $template->variables()->where('page_id', $id)->get();
foreach($variables as $variable)
    $data[$variable->name] = $variable->value;
// ...
```

Comment: The second solution works, since there I can just pass the `Page` id directly. In the first solution, I can't know which `Page` the `Template` belongs to, because the `Template` might be used by multiple `Pages`.

Comment: I see. I'm guessing the setup/query could be done in a much simpler way. But I can't really tell how...